# excel data validatoin and filtering

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It is a bit tricky to explain my requirements, hence I will do it with an example for more clarity.

I have the following requirements in Excel 2010 and not sure how to define the data validation

There are two tabs, tab "tA" and tab "tB"
There are two columns on the first tab "cA" "cB" "cC" 
There are three columns on the second tab "cD" "cE" "cF"

Column cA has data validation drop down list from second tab (column cD) with values "Yes" and "No"

Column cB has also data validation list from second tab (column cE)

Column cC has indirect data validation from column cB

The challenge I have is want to apply a filter on column values on cC which is dependent on column cA or column cD, so for example only show values on cC where the listed values in the second tab column cD match values in cA

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is indirect data validation?  An example table or a screen shot could be very helpful addition to your text description.

Answer (score 1):

=if(cD=cA,cC,"")

not sure what you want to display when cA does not equal cD. and I am not sure how you are determining what the value for cC, but however that is determined, put that in the true part of the if statement.